# how to return _version_ as string in SOLR

Tags: javascript, node.js, solr

Solr is returning the value of `_version_` field (used for optimistic concurrency) as integer. When doing `JSON.parse()` on the returned document,  `_version_` number is getting rounded because the number is just too big to be represented in javascript.

How do I force solr to return `_version_` as string instead? Doing some tricks on the client side to avoid the problem is also possible, but I'd prefer to not create a problem with too big numbers in the first place. I am using Solr 8.8.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I am using node to make GET requests. Transformation from string to json is done by the `json()` function.

```
static async documentWithId(id:string){
let url = 'someurlq=id%3A'+id;

let rawResponse = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', // or 'PUT',
});

if(rawResponse.status == 200){
  let jsonResponse = await rawResponse.json();
  if(jsonResponse.response.numFound){
    return {document: jsonResponse.response.docs[0]};
  }else{
    return {document:false};
  }
}else{
  console.error("SOLR query returned non 200 response");
  return {document:"UNKNOWN"};
}
```

}

Comment: Well, I'd say it's your JSON reader implementation that lacks proper handling of big numbers. AFAIK there's no limitation in the JSON specification. Better look at how to handle it in JS rather than wanting Solr to return it as string.

Comment: Also you mention rounding, are you sure rounding doesn't happend when displaying the value? Rounding when parsing sounds quite weird.

Comment: @GaëlJ thank you for stopping by. To temporary avoid big int problem I changed the definition of `_version_` field to `pint` (default is `plong`). You are right about the json. A custom solution is needed to handle values with large numbers.

Comment: @GaëlJ  I am not sure if changing to pint is causing any unwanted side effects. I noticed that many documents have negative `_version_` value.

Answer (score 0):

The `_version_` field used by Solr for its normal optimistic concurrency also has important semantics in how updates are distributed to replicas in SolrCloud, `and MUST be assigned internally by Solr`. Users can not re-purpose that field and specify it as the versionField for use in the DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessorFactory configuration.

Optimistic Concurrency is a feature of Solr that can be used by client applications which update/replace documents to ensure that the document they are replacing/updating has not been concurrently modified by another client application. This feature works by requiring a `_version_` field on all documents in the index, and comparing that to a `_version_` specified as part of the update command. By default, Solr’s Schema includes a `_version_` field, and this field is automatically added to each new document.

As the field is internally defined and used you cannot change the field type of the field.

You are free to introduce another field(s) if required.

If you are using Java as programming language then you can convert it as below.

```
String strVersion = Long.toString(_version_);
```

Comment: Thank you for stopping by. I am using node fetch api to make get requests. json() function is called on the response and that in turn returns the truncated `_version_` field. It appears that converting to string on the client side is pointless if the json transformation has already been done

Comment: It would be good to convert it at the server if you have any rest api exposed for your front end...You can perform the conversion at the backend side.